# Compiling android app on command line doesn't reference the R class correctly

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile an app that I pulled of github. The project is probably made with eclipse but I am trying to do it through command line using `ant debug`. But all references to symbols in the R class don't get recognized, the error I get is:

```
[javac] /home/ojs/tolvur/forritun/java/heklapunch/src/is/heklapunch/MainActivity.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
[javac]                                ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable activity_main
[javac]   location: class layout
[javac] /home/ojs/tolvur/forritun/java/heklapunch/src/is/heklapunch/MainActivity.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         editBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.saved_name);
[javac]                                               ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable saved_name
[javac]   location: class id
[javac] /home/ojs/tolvur/forritun/java/heklapunch/src/is/heklapunch/MainActivity.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
[javac]                                    ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable main_menu
[javac]   location: class menu
[javac] /home/ojs/tolvur/forritun/java/heklapunch/src/is/heklapunch/MainActivity.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             case R.id.main_test:
[javac]                      ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable main_test
[javac]   location: class id
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 4 errors

BUILD FAILED
/home/ojs/tolvur/forritun/java/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:705: The following     error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ojs/tolvur/forritun/java/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:718: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The R.java file is present and the symbols are in it so what is wrong here? I do not import android.R (it is imported in the upstream but I commented it out after I first got this error).

I haven't changed the source code except commenting out the import for android.R and building the build.xml file using `android update project --target 4 --path .`

All ideas would be very welcome.

==EDIT1==

The app I am trying to build is https://github.com/robotis/heklapunch

==EDIT2==

Running lint on the project generates 19 errors and 40 warnings in the xml I guess that could be related :-)

==EDIT3==

Updating my SDK (by first doing `android update sdk -u`, then `android update sdk -u --filter tools,platform-tools` but still not getting build tools installed and finally `android sdk` and selecting `build tools` there to install) and fetching the git project again solved my problem. I have no idea what was wrong though.

Comment: Can you post the link to the app on github ? So you did, thanks ;-)